# How can I change LauncherPro shortcut intents without using the Shortcut option on my NookColor?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, launcherpro, nook-color

I have a rooted NookColor and am using launcherpro as my home app. I would like to change the dock's shortcuts to different applications but the problem is a rooted nookcolor does not support the shortcut intent. If you try to use it, it will crash launcherpro. Is there another way I can change the shortcuts?

Comment: Where is that information stored?  In a DB?  I'm not that familiar with how .apk files work but it seems to me that user specific data like this wouldn't be stored inside the apk and would be in some place you could edit manually.

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure.  Actually, I think LP has a backup feature.  I might be able to hand edit the backup file and restore it?  Going to see what damage I can do... :)

Comment: Let me know how it goes. If that doesn't work try editing and restoring a titanium backup backup.